# WooCommerce sidebar wrong display

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem with WooCommerce sidebar on archive-page and categories page,
Its display under my products ( right after page-pagi )

I tried to style it with css, like

```
.woocommerce .products ul, .woocommerce ul.products { width: 70%; float: right )
.sidebar { width: 29%; float: left;}
```

But it looks like it's in completely another section or something cause this have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme isn't configured to work with woocommerce, and you've just installed it, it will probably be totally messed up. What you can do is add your own containers. Put these in functions.php

```
if (!function_exists('custom_open_woocommerce_content_wrappers')) {
    function custom_open_woocommerce_content_wrappers(){
        echo '<div class="container shop_container"><div class="row">';
    }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_close_woocommerce_content_wrappers')) {
    function custom_close_woocommerce_content_wrappers(){
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_product_wrapper_open')) {
    function custom_product_wrapper_open(){
        echo '<div class="span8 content_with_right_sidebar">';
    }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_product_wrapper_close')) {
    function custom_product_wrapper_close(){
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar')) {
    function custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar() {
        echo '<aside class="span4 sidebar sidebar_right">';
        dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Name Goes Here');
        echo '</aside>';
    }
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar', 20);

if (!function_exists('custom_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers')) {
    function custom_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers(){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'custom_open_woocommerce_content_wrappers', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'custom_close_woocommerce_content_wrappers', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'custom_product_wrapper_open', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_product_wrapper_close', 10 );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers' );
```

This will create a wrapper with a right sidebar. And you can style it with

```
.container{
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row{
    width: 100%;
}

.row:before,
.row:after{
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}

.row:after{
    clear: both;
}

.row > [class*="span"]{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > [class*="span"]:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.row .span8 {width: 65.81196581196581%;}
.row .span4 {width: 31.62393162393162%;}
```

Etc.

You can customize the wrappers to your liking, add options to choose left/right no sidebar by linking it with customizer, etc.

Basically, you can add your own classes in those divs, that will suit your needs. This one has these classes because when I'm working with themes I use grid that has 12 columns, and it has container with 1170px width and row and spans (1-12 corresponding to columns).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for complex solution, theme which i use suppose to have WooCommerce configuration , buti see that autor completle ignore woo templates and just use his own page builder - which whould be gr8 but WooComerce block used in this page builder dont work with some Woo fetures like  product sorting etc.

Comment: I just tried to use this code, but it looks like , it have no effect on product archive page -

Comment: When you go to shop page, nothing happens? This is ood, should work normally. The alternative is to create a woocommerce folder in your theme folder, and copy the template files from woocommerce and add your own wrappers :\ I'll check my solution, but it should be working. What theme are you using?

Comment: Maybe your theme has these files pulled out in the theme, you should contact your theme support to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for respone, im useing The Stormer by premium codeing, maybe i made something wrong, but i contacted support and they claim that editing this page by css will had big inpact on each site and will generate alot of Bugs.

Comment: Yeah, they are full of bs. Does your theme have a woocommerce folder in it?

Comment: I googled it, that is a shop theme and should be good out of the box. Support should fix your issue

Comment: Thank you for response, well support suggest just to do not use sidebar :)

Comment: That's a very stupid suggestion. You should have picked a better theme. Did you look for the woocommerce folder inside your theme?

Comment: Yes i checked css and woocomerce tempates , sidebar is made display:none, when i uncheck it, its show under products on page-archive , and all other pages , like single-product page etc ( which i dont want) . 
For now i manage to register my own sidebar, decrease width of product section and place my sidebar on free space on left . I know its not good solution but without php knowlage i dont have better :(

Comment: The problem is that meddling blindly on the template files could mess things up even more. You should have researched the theme a bit more before the purchase :\

Comment: Thank you for respone, theme  was useing page builder and author completle ignore woocomerce templats, so i created completly new template for product archive's etc and now its work fine ...

Answer (score 0):

set **.woocommerce**  and **.sidebar** padding and margin  = 0